# Solving distance with acceleration and velocity given and getting two different answers using two different equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity, distance

Frictional forces from brake pads are responsible for stopping an automobile. A car is moving at $35.0 \:\mathrm{m/s}$. If the car's brakes are capable of generating a deceleration rate of $6.00 \:\mathrm{m/s^2}$, then how many meters will this vehicle move before coming to a stop?

If I use the formula $\frac{v_{final}^2-v_{initial}^2}{2 a}$ I get $102 \:\mathrm{meters}$ but If I use the formula $a=v/t$ I get $6=35/t$. When I solve for time $t$ I get $5.833 \:\mathrm{s}$. I then use the formula $v=d/t$ and plug in time $t$. When I solve for distance $d$ I get $204 \:\mathrm{meters}$, which is double that of my previous answer.

Which answer is right and why?

Comment: The formulas $a=\frac{v}{t}$ and $v=\frac{x}{t}$ should rather be $a=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}$ and $v=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$. Otherwise you are assuming $v$ and $x$ constant through the times $t$

Comment: Note that a *deceleration* means *negative* $a$. So $a=-6\:\mathrm{m/s^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

> Velocity=Distance/Time

You use this equation, assuming Velocity is constant. But in reality, is the velocity constant? If not, how do you remedy this?

It is never good to use equations without knowing why they work, or how they were derived. To fully understand the equations, the best practice is deriving them yourselves. At school all I was ever taught was to blindly remember the equations. If you have knowledge of calculus, and you understand the premise of the equations, trust me, derive them first, if you need help look online, and you'll never forget how they work again.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the equations you have supplied are based on some assumption. The equation

$$s = \frac{v^2-u^2}{2a}$$

assumes a constant acceleration (which, in this case, is valid). The other equation

$$v = \frac{s}{t}$$

assumes a constant velocity. (Not valid here).

The proper definitions (to the best of my knowledge) of velocity and acceleration require the use of calculus to be expressed. Velocity is given as follows:

$$v = \frac{ds}{dt}$$

For acceleration,

$$a = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{d^2s}{dt^2}$$

These are true provided that the displacement, velocity and acceleration are all positive in the same direction. It is from these equations that we derive the equations based on assumptions.

For example, lets derive an equation based on the assumption that the acceleration is constant.

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = a = constant$$

Integrate both sides,

$$v = at + c$$

where $c$ is the constant of integration. Apply boundary condition:

$$t=0, v=u$$

$$u = c$$

$$\therefore v = u + at$$

This should be familiar as one of the suvat equations, all of which are based on the assumption of a constant acceleration.